# HTTPD dies on FreeBSD if multiple connenctions are open from same client

Tags: iptables, firewall, freebsd, httpd, ipfw

I've asked this question on StackOverflow, but nobody answered, until yesterday... and the answer was a suggestion... to ask this here :). So... can someone help me with this :

I'm new in networking and security and I have a problem with HTTPD server on FreeBSD. If someone make a lot of requests, httpd servers dies.... Can anyone tell me a solution to prevent `httpd` from dying or how to add and `ipfw` rule that will block for 60 seconds any connection to the server from an IP that has made over 5 requests/second in the past second.

ie : if someone opens the website and keeps F5 button pressed, `httpd` dies... `httpd` restart is not working anymore, so I need to `httpd stop` / `httpd start` ....

This is what I found for `iptables`:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 5 -j DROP
```

Comment: . . . error message? Logs? *Something?* [**I'm beggin' ya man!**](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) (we really need waaaaaay more detail to even begin to speculate about guessing)

Comment: error message in browser... "server taking to long to respond" or something like that...and in logs, nothing...

Comment: nothing in the server logs? Can't be.... gotta be something... (check `/var/log/messages` if it's actually dying -- there should be an "httpd Exited with signal xxxx" in there...) If there's really nothing try attaching a debugger to Apache.

Comment: in /var/log/messages i see kernel: pid 19457 (httpd), uid 80: exited on signal 11 but i'm not sure if this is the message i was looking for. ... apache is not dying...the httpd process is still listed in ps but it is not responding in browser...

Answer (score 0):

As a Quick answer I would suggest the following for the local pf:
(i am using it for SSH brutforce attempts)

```
# vi /etc/pf.conf

table <bruteforce> persist
block quick from <bruteforce>

pass inet proto tcp from any to any port http flags S/SA keep state (max-src-conn 5, max-src-conn-rate 5/30, overload <bruteforce> flush global)
```

(inspired form [here](http://128bitstudios.com/2010/06/13/stopping-ssh-brute-force-attacks-with-pf-on-freebsd/))

EDIT:
your have to enable pf of course :)

```
# vi /etc/rc.conf

pf_enable="YES"
pf_rules="/etc/pf.conf"
pflog_enable="YES"
```